# The window to add attachments appears behind the page

Tags: display-form

I am opening a page from another page, and when I click the paperclip to add an attachment to the attachment field, the window for the upload appears behind the page???
I am guessing this is because the first page is a dialog and the system assumes it is in control.  however it is not the latest dialog page and should not be the control.

I do not have any properties to change that I know of this is system behaviour?
Please help if you have ever seen this and know the solution.

Marc.

Comment: Could you share more on how you use the "paperclip" to launch the 2nd dialog?